# Spectrum of localized ring as the germ at a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm reading Eisenbud and Harris's The Geometry of Schemes, and in particular I'm trying to make sense of the example in section II.1.2 when they explain how the scheme $X = \operatorname{Spec} K[x]_{(x)}$ can be viewed as the germ of $\mathbb{A}^1_K$ at the origin. The natural map $K[x] \to K[x]_{(x)}$ gives a morphism of schemes $X \to \mathbb{A}^1_K$, and they claim that this allows one to view $X$ as a subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1_K$.  My questions are

1. How does one give $X \subset \mathbb{A}^1_K$ the structure of a subscheme even if its not closed nor open in $\mathbb{A}^1_K$, and
2. How would one check that the scheme structures on $X = \operatorname{Spec} K[x]_{(x)}$ and whatever subscheme structure $X$ inherits from $\mathbb{A}^1_K$ are the same?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "subscheme" for question 1? 2. If you write `\operatorname{Spec}` inside math mode, this produces $\operatorname{Spec}$ which formats nicely. I've made the upgrade for you in your post this time.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I'm just looking for clarification on what Eisenbud and Harris mean when they write "The inclusion of $K[x]$ into $K[x]_{(x)}$ induces a map $X \to \mathbb{A}^1_K$, so that we may think of $X$ as a subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1_K$".

Comment: Perhaps noting that the structure sheaf on $X$ is the inverse image under $X \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ of the structure sheaf on $\mathbb{A}^1$?